# Why do we need to install minitest gem sometimes?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, minitest

I am using Ruby 2.0.

Sometimes I encounter cases where I can't just simply `require 'minitest'`. It gives me

```
irb> require 'minitest'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- minitest
from rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

I need to install minitest gem first. However I thought minitest is bundled in the Ruby standard library.

When do we need to explicitly install minitest gem via `gem install` or Gemfile?

If installing explicitly is required, should Gemfile `bundle install` preferred over `gem install`?

#### update

I myself use rbenv. I install my Ruby through rbenv as well.
My ruby version is ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-darwin13.0.2]

Comment: What do you mean when you say you can't require it? Do you get an error? What error message?

Comment: @Max It will say "cannot load such file" (see my update)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I realized MiniTest had some incompatible updates from 4.x to 5.x
And somehow I was using version 5.x but my problem seems to occur when 4.x is used.

Here is when it works as expected:

```
irb> require 'minitest'
=> true
irb> require 'minitest/autorun'
=> true
irb> MiniTest::Test
=> Minitest::Test
irb> MiniTest.constants
=> [:Parallel, :VERSION, :Runnable, :AbstractReporter, :Reporter, :ProgressReporter, :StatisticsReporter, :SummaryReporter, :CompositeReporter, :Assertion, :Skip, :UnexpectedError, :Guard, :BacktraceFilter, :Test, :Assertions, :Unit, :Spec, :Expectations, :Mock]
irb> MiniTest::Unit::VERSION
=> "5.3.2"
```

Here is when it is not. I installed a fresh copy of Ruby 2.1 and reproduced the following.

```
irb> require 'minitest'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- minitest
irb> require 'minitest/autorun'
=> true
irb> MiniTest::Test
NameError: uninitialized constant MiniTest::Test
irb> MiniTest.constants
=> [:Assertion, :Skip, :BacktraceFilter, :Assertions, :Unit, :Spec, :Expectations, :Mock]
irb> MiniTest::Unit::VERSION
=> "4.7.5"
```

#### Summary

So I guess when an older minitest version is used, I should install version 5 explictly via Gemfile/bundler.

Answer (score 1):

If you install through **gem**, all system wide gem will depend upon that version. While **bundle** install make sure all dependencies in your gem file are available to your application.

```
sunspot_rails
  nokogiri (>= 1.2.0)

webrat
  nokogiri (>= 1.3)
```

Both gem require **nokogiri** but they do have preferred version number. In this scenario if you install through **gem**, you will get version conflict. But **bundle** will intelligently handle that version demand for you.

Comment: I think `gem` can install multiple versions of a gem to handle situations like this.

Comment: @Max RubyGems will always install the latest version unless you tell it otherwise, and it will always use the latest version period (which is why you want Bundler).